# php send 404 header problems

Tags: php, seo, http-status-code-404

A quick question. I know how to send a 404 header in php but when I do the page still continues to load content. In this case must I kill the script also with die(). I have a custom home made cms which is very fast and well suited to my site. But for some reason google has indexed an improper link to the site that was most likely due to some old code that no longer exists. What is happening is that directories such as "/AWebDirectory/AndAnother/function.fopen/" has gotten appended to the url i.e.

```
www.someurl.com/index.php/AWebDirectory/AndAnother/function.fopen/
```

This is not throwing a 404 as index.php exists but the css and stuff is not loading due to the directory structure. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to handle this with `.htaccess` not with PHP. You have to re-write those URLs to `index.php`, if you want to get rid of them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to exit the script or it will just keep going.  This is normal.  I'm not 100% sure, but I think you might be looking for a redirect:

```
<?php

/**
 * @see http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php
 */

header("Location: http://www.example.com/"); /* Redirect browser */

/* Make sure that code below does not get executed when we redirect. */
exit;
?>
```

Try using both the 404 header, and redirect to your custom 404 page.  That should get you up and running.

Comment: Why exit? 404 pages are quite normal, you know, they do have content, like other pages. What matters is the header. You are not even giving an example with the `404` error, but one with a redirect.

Comment: He's already got the 404 header bit based on the question he asked.  After the exit the redirect occurs, if I'm not mistaken.